# Writing images and text to files using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-writing

I am trying to use beautiful soup to scrape images from multiple URLs, and then write the URLs and the images to a file. The file format would look like:

TEXT OF URL_1

img_1 (ACTUAL IMAGE SHOWN)

img_2 (ACTUAL IMAGE SHOWN)

TEXT OF URL_2

img_1 (ACTUAL IMAGE SHOWN)

The first few lines of my output file right now looks like:

```
Company : Firehydrant     URL : https://www.firehydrant.io/âPNG


IHDRLf9ÃŒ∫   pHYsöúYiTXtXML:com.adobe.xmp<?xpacket begin="Ôªø" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?> <x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.6-c148 79.164036, 2019/08/13-01:06:57  

...
```

How can I view my file with the images actually showing instead of the binary? Or is there a different way of doing this? **Sorry if this is a really stupid question!!**

Here is my code right now for 1 website:

```
with open(file_name, 'wb') as img_file:

    option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    option.add_argument(" — incognito")
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver', chrome_options=option)

    url = 'https://www.firehydrant.io/'

    browser.get(url)
    timeout = 10
    WebDriverWait(browser, timeout)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
    images = soup.find_all("img")

    found_first_image = False
    for image in images:
        src = image['src']
        if(found_first_image == False): # ADD THE TEXT FOR THE COMPANY/URL
            found_first_image = True
            string = ("URL : " + url).encode('utf-8') 
            img_file.write(string)

        # removing everything after the '?' if there is one in the src tag
        src = urljoin(url, src)
        if("?" in src):
            pos = src.index("?")
            src = src[:pos]
        parsed = urlparse(src)
        if(bool(parsed.netloc) and bool(parsed.scheme)): # download the image and write it to the file
            response = requests.get(src)
            URLFile.write(response.content)
```

Comment: How do you want to actually view the file? The file might be better structured as json with base64 encoding for the images embedded in a json value or store the files separately and zip all the files up for distribution

Comment: The way you need to think about this: files *don't actually contain* images or text or anything else. They contain *bytes* - raw data. It's up to *the program you use to view the file*, to decide what that data actually *means*, and display something appropriate. When you view, for example, a .html file in a text editor, it looks different from what you see in a web browser - because those differing *interpretations* are forced onto the same data by those programs.

Comment: I was hoping to just view it in text edit - there are thousands of websites being crawled, and I don't want to store all of the images in various folders/directory and click through one-by-one. If I don't write the text I am printing to my file (the url/company name) and just write the images and then open it in text edit, I can see the first image visibly but not any of the rest. And when I keep the text mixed with the images, I see all of the text and images as symbols when opening in text edit.

Comment: @jbug123 have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Store your images as image files outside rather than putting them here as text. Just keep a unique id for the image when you write it and put that unique id in your text file instead of the image. For saving image, `cv2.imread` can be used and for generating unique number use:

```
import uuid

uuid.uuid1().hex
```

Comment: Thank you Abhishek, though I would prefer to not save each image as a file. Is there a workaround to my original question/code?